# Error de principiante sql al conseguir valores de dos tablas diferentes

Tags: sql

Existe la tabla coche y cliente, se supone que quiero hacer una consulta para poder obtener el dni de todos los cliente que viven en cierta ciudad y al mismo tiempo tienen un coche registrado en la empresa, esta me funciona cuando solo existe un cliente para el resultado pero cuando son dos a más deja me arroja un error de que la subconsulta regresa más de una linea

```
SELECT coche.dni
from coche 
INNER JOIN cliente ON coche.dni=cliente.dni
WHERE coche.dni = (SELECT cliente.dni from cliente WHERE Ciudad = 'valencia');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@elsopas tienes la consulta mal. Yo haria lo siguiente:

```
SELECT coche.dni FROM coche
INNER JOIN cliente ON coche.dni = cliente.dni
WHERE cliente.Ciudad = 'Valencia'
```

Esto lo que estas haciendo es lo siguiente dame todos los dnis de la tabla de coches que este vinculado el dni de la tabla de coches con la de clientes, donde en la tabla clientes su ciudad sea **Valencia**

Asi te devolvera todos los resultados.

Answer (score 0):

Tu consulta, tal como la planteas debería ser:

```
SELECT coche.dni
from coche 
INNER JOIN cliente ON coche.dni=cliente.dni
WHERE coche.dni in (SELECT cliente.dni from cliente WHERE Ciudad = 'valencia');
```

Es decir, cambiando el "=" por el "in".

Aunque lo más eficiente sería:

```
SELECT coche.dni
from coche 
INNER JOIN cliente ON coche.dni=cliente.dni
WHERE cliente.ciudad = 'valencia'
```